# What is #[warn(unstable)] about in Rust?

Tags: io, rust

I have a really simple cat function written in the Rust 1.0 alpha.

```
use std::io;

fn main(){
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    loop {
        let input = reader.read_line().ok().expect("Failed to read line");
        print!("{}", input);
    }
}
```

When I compile it, I get the following warnings:

```
bindings.rs:5:26: 5:35 warning: use of unstable item, #[warn(unstable)] on by default
bindings.rs:5         let mut reader = io::stdin();
                                       ^~~~~~~~~
bindings.rs:6:28: 6:39 warning: use of unstable item, #[warn(unstable)] on by default
bindings.rs:6         let input = reader.read_line().ok().expect("Failed to read line");
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there a way to remedy these warnings?

Comment: It's not, it's due to your code. :-)

Comment: This equates to a potential deprecation warning, but where the replacement is not yet implemented. How do I squelch such warnings?

Comment: To answer my question: `#![allow(unstable)]` does the trick.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the 1.0 release, Rust wants to provide a very strong guarantee about what features of the language and standard library will be available for the *entire life of the language*. This is not an easy feat!

New, untested, or just not-fully-cooked features will be marked with a stability attribute, and you [won't be able to use unstable features in the beta or release](http://blog.rust-lang.org/2014/12/12/1.0-Timeline.html). You will only be able to use them in the nightly builds.

During the *alpha* however, they are simply warnings. If you need to use a feature in the alpha and it's marked as `unstable`, then you will want to make sure it becomes stable (or you find an alternate solution) before the beta!

In this case, the entire IO subsystem is undergoing last-minute changes, so it's marked as unstable.

**Edit 1**

When [PR 21543](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21543) lands, the current world known as `std::io` will be renamed as `std::old_io`. Newly-written code will go into `std::io` and the old version will be deprecated.

Comment: Is there a roadmap for IO anywhere? Maybe in the rust repo?

Comment: The two I know of would be the [beta stabilization metabug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20761) and the [IO reform RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/517/)