# What is the stable alternative of to_string()

Tags: rust

I'm working my way through the [rust book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-alpha/book).  In the Strings chapter a lot of the examples use to_string() which my version of the compiler(rustc 1.0.0-dev) gives the following warning

```
strings.rs:3:23: 3:34 warning: use of unstable item, #[warn(unstable)] on by default
strings.rs:3   let mut s = "Hello".to_string();
```

Code:

```
fn main() {
  let mut s = "Hello".to_string();
  println!("{}", s);
}
```

I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872753/what-is-warnunstable-about-in-rust) that this is because the API is likely to change, but I would like to know what I should use instead if I want to convert a string slice (str&) to a String

Comment: I think that at this moment there is no stable alternative! We will just have to bear the wasrnings until the compiler goes into beta. Or you can disable the warning, if you prefer.

Comment: There's a similar warning for `range_step` at the moment. No actual replacement here as well. I guess there will be a couple of changes till beta version.

Comment: It's an Alpha release, which implies that the whole thing is unstable, warnings or no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *work around* these things, e.g. `format!("Hello")`, but I really wouldn’t bother for the moment.